# Восстановление пароля root в MySQL под Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd, mariadb

Имеется Windows 10, xampp v.3.2.2 с mariadb

Случилось так что задал какой то мудреный пароль для пользователя root и забыл его где нибудь сохранить.

Пытаюсь запустить сервер без привилегий так

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

а потом из другой консоли меняем пароль

```
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE user ='root';
```

и выхожу из него уже mysqladmin командой, не набирая -uroot ...

```
mysqladmin shutdown
```

Но ничего не происходит.

```
mysql --version  команда выдает следующее
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)
```

Такой способ раньше работал.Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Задайте директиву skip-grant-tables через my.ini и перезагрузите сервер.

Comment: Так тоже пробовал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

mysql --user=root mysql

update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Comment: У меня нет такого mysqld_safe.ехе файла. "mysqld_safe" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan - у Вас MySQL под Виндовс ???

Comment: Процедура сброса по ссылке https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Ага.Win 10, xampp v.3.2.2

Comment: @gecube  Тут говорится как если бы MySQLбыл бы инсталлирован как сервис.MySQL в xampp поставляется в виде пакета.Хотя хорошая ссылка .почитаю дальше ,может что то упустил

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql 5.7

mysql --user=root mysql
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("new_password") where User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```